# Is it possible to use NewRelic for generic availability monitoring of third-party service without installing New Relic agent on it?

Tags: newrelic

We use NewRelic for our application. We have its agents installed in our web and mobile applications and all works fine.

Now we are interested if it is possible to monitor third-party service that we heavily rely on as it is business critical and we want to know if this service goes offline so that we can be proactive if there is any data that doesn’t get propagated.

We know there are tools like [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/) but anyway we are interested if it is possible to achieve that kind of monitoring using NewRelic for sites that do not have NewRelic agent installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we don't have a good solutions for this, however, we have a new Synthetics Product that is currently in private Beta testing that sounds like it is what you are looking for.  See our docs site for more information: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/new-relic-synthetics  Also, you can sign up for Product Updates and release news here: http://newrelic.com/synthetics

Comment: Kristen, thanks for the answer! I will look through the docs you mentioned.